# Difference between CALL on external contract address function and creating contract object with external address then calling function?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

What's the difference between these two forms of calling methods on external contracts?

```
contract A {
    function foo() {
    }
}

contract B {

  function createFoo (address _contractAddress){
    Contract A = A(_contractAddress);
    A.foo();
  }

  function callFoo (address _contractAddress) {
    address newAddress = _contractAddress;
    newAddress.call(bytes4(sha3("foo()")));
  }
}
```

`createFoo` and `callFoo` seem to do the same thing. How are they different?

Comment: On the EVM level, they are the same - they are both `CALL`s. On Solidity level, they are different when it comes to error propagation

Comment: @Michael O'Rourke a little offtopic here: when I try to compile that code I receive DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique. Contract A = A(_contractAddress); btw.  I have not seen such declaration anywhere. I may miss something.

Comment: inside createFoo, it should really be:
A a = A(_contractAddress); a.foo();

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a huge difference between them

```
function createFoo (address _contractAddress){
    Contract A = A(_contractAddress);
    A.foo();
}
```

If `foo()` fails the call to `createFoo()` will also fail and it will propagate reversing any change you have made.

Another difference is you can retrieve the value returned by `foo()`. If the function returned an address you can assign to a variable.

```
address who = A.foo();
```

In the second case if `foo()` fails, call will return false. But it will not reverse changes you have made, you have to explicitely call `revert()`.

```
function callFoo (address _contractAddress) {
    address newAddress = _contractAddress;
    newAddress.call(bytes4(sha3("foo()")));
}
```

And you do not have access to the value returned by `foo()`, call only return true if it executed successfully or false if it has failed.

Comment: And what if `_contractAddress == this`? Will this be external call in the second case?

Comment: @k06a Yes, if you use `.call()` it always be an external call.

Answer (score 6):

On EVM level, they are the same. They are both `CALL`s (vs `DELEGATECALL` or `CALLCODE`), which creates an internal transaction when the function `createFoo` or `callFoo` is called.

On Solidity level, they are different. Especially when it comes to error handling (invalid OPCODE jumping)

`A.foo()` calls the function and you also get the return value. It also propagates errors. This obviously require you to know the contract ABI beforehand. This is the safest way to call another contract.

`aAddress.call(bytes4(sha3("foo()")))` is similar, except it does not require the ABI to be known by your contract. This however does not propagate errors, unless remaining gas becomes zero. You can force it to propagate errors by forwarding all your remaining gas to the call, however you may introduce re-entrancy.